# Reset a variable via void function

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int test = 1;

    resetTest();

    Console.Write(test); // Should be 0
}

static void resetTest()
{
    test = 0;
}
```

Why doesn't it work? How can I get it? (I don't wanna to use int function and return to the variable) Now I have an error message which says that the variable test is undefined on the function resetTest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because test is defined within the scope of your Main method.

You'll need to move it outside that method for this to work.

Something like:

```
static int test = 1; 

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    resetTest();

    Console.Write(test); // Should be 0
}

static void resetTest()
{
    test = 0;
}
```

Comment: I understand, Thank you very much. I'll mark you answer in 8 min.

Comment: While global variables are useful one has to be careful using them. It can become your worst nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

The variable test is local to the Main procedure.  You would have to declare it outside of that scope.

```
static int test = 0;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  test = 1;
  Console.Write(test); // Should be 1
  resetTest();
  Console.Write(test); // Should be 0
}

static void resetTest()
{
  test = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue with the void return. The problem is that test is scoped to the Main method. You'd have to make it a static field to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

this will work

```
static int test = 1;
static void Main(string[] args)
{


    reserTest();

    Console.Write(test); // Should be 0
}

static void resetTest()
{
    test = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

test is a local variable to your Main function. So you can't access it from a separate function.

You need to promote it to a (static, in your case) member variable of your class if you want to do that.

Answer (score 2):

`test` is a local variable to `Main()`. So `resetTest()` cannot even access it, forget about resetting it.

Answer (score 2):

`test` is not accessible in your function `resetTest()` because the scope of the local variable `test` is your `Main` function.

You have to pass it by ref if you want to change the value in the function `resetTest()`

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options.

1) You can pass the variable, by reference, to the function:

```
static void resetTest(ref int test)
{
    test = 0;
}
```

This allows you to change this (or any other) variable.

2) You can declare it outside of Main, as a static int local to the type itself:

```
static int test;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    resetTest();

    Console.Write(test); // Should be 0
}

static void resetTest()
{
    test = 0;
}
```

This puts it in scope for the entire *type*.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because you defined `test` to be local to the `Main` static method. Try and define it as

```
private static int test = 1;
```

Within your class definition, but outside any method.

Answer (score 2):

This is a scope and static variable problem. The scope of test right now is only to the main function, so resetTest cannot even access it.

Currently you've set resetTest to be a [static method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29#Static_methods). To change any variable within a static method, that variable would either need to be passed as a reference (answered in another answer) or the variable would need to be a static variable of that class.

So you have something of a mismatched bit of code, at current.

```
public class SomeClass {
   public int test = 1;

   static void Main(string[] args) {   
       SomeClass myClass = new SomeClass(); // Will instantiate test as 1
       myClass.resetTest();

       Console.Write(myClass.test); // Should be 0
   }

   public void resetTest() {
       test = 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The test Variable is not Rested ,and if you want to achieve that ,not only for test but for any Int into you're app. in that way you should pass Variable by [Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int test = 1;
    reserTest(ref test);

    Console.Write(test); // Should be 0 now
}

static void resetTest(ref int i)
{
    i = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You defined the "test" variable inside the Main method, so it only exists inside it.

You could (Don't do it, just because you can doesn't mean you should) 1:

- Place the declaration outside the method

  ```
  int test = 1;

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      resetTest();

      Console.Write(test); // Should be 0
  }

  static void resetTest()
  {
      test = 0;
  }
  ```
- Send the variable by reference:

  ```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      int test = 1;
      resetTest(ref test);

      Console.Write(test); // Should be 0
  }

  static void resetTest(ref int test)
  {
      test = 0;
  }
  ```

Either way you should read a bit about scopes: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpVariableScopes.aspx